# Computing frequent itemsets with duplicate items in transactions

Tags: transactions, data-mining, apriori

**Background** Most of the examples on frequent itemset mining have transactions with unique items. For example `{1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3,5,6}, {6}`. I'm interested in knowing if having duplicates in transactions affects the outcomes. For instance `{1,2,1}, {2,2,3}, {4,3}, {4,1,2,4,2,6}`

**Question** Using the apriori algorithm, what would be the support for 1-items in the transaction database `{1,2,1}, {2,2,3}, {4,3}, {4,1,2,4,2,6}`? I think the result would be:

```
{1}: 2
{2}: 3
{3}: 2
{4}: 2
{6}: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The "default" FIM algorithms don't allow duplicates.

But you can trivially encode duplicates as additional items, i.e.

```
{ Beer, Beer }  ->  { Beer, Beer_2 }
```

and then proceed as usual. You will then get boring assoication rules such as

```
{ Beer_2 } -> { Beer }
```

i.e. people who bought a second beer, also bought a first beer.

These a trivial to prune from the result though: Never consider to move `x` to the right hand side, when `x_2` is on the left, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the effect of allowing duplicates on the algorithms? Does it lead to incorrect frequent patterns being reported?

Answer (score 1):

The original problem of frequent itemset mining does not have quantities, that is an item can only occur zero or once in a transaction. Therefore, the case that you mentionned is undefined.

If you want to allow duplicates, you could have a look at variations of the problem of itemset mining.

In "**high utility itemset mining**",  each item can appears more than once and each item can also have a weight such as a unit profit.  The goal of high utility itemset mining is to find itemsets with high utility (e.g. high profit).  If you are curious you could have a look at the paper to see how they define the utility based on how many times the item appear in a transaction and the weight.  The problem of high utility mining is a more general problem than the problem of duplicates. You could use an algorithm for high utility itemset mining such as FHM and HUI-Miner and it would work with the problem of duplicates if you give a weight of 1 to each item.  You can get a Java implementation of the HUI-Miner in the [Java SPMF data mining library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) if you are curious.

Another variation is "weighted itemset mining" where items have weights but cannot appear more than once.

If you look a little bit at these variations and others, I think that someone has certainly adressed this problem already.

Answer (score 1):

In association rule mining, an item is frequent iff it is repeated in multiple transactions not in a single transaction. This is why you don't need to have duplicate items in a transaction.
That's why remove any such items from that cell. And then apply apriori for good associations.